# C# SocketException when accepting connections

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I have been  trying to learn about sockets for the past day or so. I thought it would be a good idea to make a basic chat client and server to learn with, I have tried to make an asynchronous server so I don't need to use loads of threads etc and I have came into an issue I simply can't fix. When I start my server, it goes through all ok and waits at the point where it needs to wait for a connection. I then start up my makeshift 'client' that simply sends a string for now and my server crashes with a `SocketException` with the message

> Additional information: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

I don't see how my socket is not connected when it has to accept the connection in the first place. I have been using this tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) as a guide and have looked at both my code and the tutorial and still don't understand what I am doing wrong, can anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Chat_Application
{
    class Server
    {
        private Socket serverSocket = null;
        private volatile ArrayList connections = null; // will hold all client sockets
        private const int port = 1090;
        private IPAddress ipAddress = null;
        private IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = null;
        private Thread listenThread = null; // seperate thread to run the server 
        private ManualResetEvent allDone = null;

        public Server()
        {
            this.serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            this.connections = new ArrayList();
            ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet));
            ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
            listenThread = new Thread(StartListen);
            allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            listenThread.Start();
        }

        public void StartListen()
        {
            this.serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            this.serverSocket.Listen(20);
            Program.mainWin.console.Text += "\n<INFO> Socket bound, listening for connections...";

            while (true)
            {
                allDone.Reset();
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnectionAsync), serverSocket);
                Program.mainWin.console.Text += "\n<INFO> Conncetion accepted...";
                allDone.WaitOne();

            }
        }

        public void AcceptConnectionAsync(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[1024]; 
            allDone.Set();
            Socket client = (Socket) AR.AsyncState;
            int x = client.Receive(bufferBytes);
            Program.mainWin.console.Text += System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bufferBytes);

        }

        public string GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
        {
            string output = "";
            foreach (NetworkInterface item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            output = ip.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never calling `EndAccept` (from the example you linked):

```
// Get the socket that handles the client request.
Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar); // This right here
```

The socket in `ar.AsyncState` is the *listening* socket, not the connected client. AsyncState is an arbitrary object you can use to pass information to the callback method (`AcceptConnectionAsync`). In this case, you are passing the serverSocket (the second parameter below):

```
serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptConnectionAsync), serverSocket);
```

When you call `EndAccept` on the listening socket, you are getting a *new* `Socket` instance that is a specific connection to the client -- your listener socket will start the asynchronous request to accept another connection in your `while` loop in `StartListen`. The socket returned by `EndAccept` is in a connected state and ready to communicate with the other endpoint, based on this specific callback invocation (hence, the requirement to supply `IAsyncResult` as an argument).

This is referred to as the *Asynchronous Programming Model*. [MSDN has some great information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on this (as usual).

Comment: Brilliant! No idea how I overlooked that! So, let me get this straight. The listener object is essentially a copy of the socket I called .BeginAccept() on  earlier (serverSocket in my example), so by setting a new object to listener.EndAccept() I am grabbing the socket from the serverSocket? Also why do I need to pass 'AR' to the endaccept?

Comment: Edited my answer to include some more info for you :)